# Firefox и число с плавающей запятой

Tags: firefox

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: в файрфоксе `<input type="number"/>` не хочет работать с числами с плавающей запятой, а в гугл хроме все нормально. Можно как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: В смысле не хочет работать? Не показывает, показывает неправильно, вы пишите какой то код и он неправильно выполняется? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Может надо точку ставить вместо запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня всё работает. Попробуй поэкспериментировать с разделителем (точка или запятая) - вероятно, он зависит от региональных настроек.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
  document.querySelector('output').textContent = this.value
})
```

```html
<input type=number step=0.01 min=0 max=1>
<output></output>
```

Comment: а теперь вручную добавьте число с запятой она не будет работать

Comment: @AslanKussein, у меня работало - я ж проверял.